# To show a JQuery error message

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to show a JQuery dialog on error part of Ajax call. Currently I am using the below code but the message is coming in the page and not as a popup dialog. Initially when the page loads the icon also showing on the page which I don't want to show.

### .cshtml

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Error Message">
    <p>
      <span id="dialog-text"> </span>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:right; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

### Ajax call - on error I want to show the above dialog with the actual error message

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateRecord", "Client")',
    data: { "id": id, "name": clientName, "code": clientCode, "typeId": clientTypeId, "clientStatusCode": clientStatusCode },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {//alert(id);
    },
    error: function (request) {
        alert('inside error');
        $("#dialog-text").html(request.responseText);
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");

        //alert(request.responseText);
    },
});
```

Comment: are you using JQuery dialog box plugin?

Comment: yes mahesh. I am using Jquery plugin

Comment: i think you are using this one http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/. Can you pls check whether you are referring the plugin js file correctly?

Comment: Thank Mahesh. Where is the CDN location for this file.

Comment: That i am not sure. Its better you can download the js file and add to your project and from there you can refer.